# What is considered learning Torah in the bathroom?

Tags: torah-study, bathroom

It is prohibited to learn Torah in the bathroom (source needed).

How far does this prohibition go? Are we not allowed to say pesukim, but allowed to think them? Is there a difference between tanach and Torah sheba’al Peh?

Can one sing (pesukim based songs) in the bathroom (seeing as he doesn’t mean to learn, just to entertain himself)?

Can someone figure out/ check zmanim and other stuff that will help him perform mitzvos (but aren’t learning/ mitzvos themselves)?

What do our sources say about this?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48900/11532

Comment: Seems that in some sense thinking about *zmanim* should be OK. How else could one time how long one can stay in the shower before he has to run to shacharit minyan?

Comment: Watch out, @DanF, there are those who argue it's assur to shower before Shacharit, that it's just as arrogant as eating

Comment: @DanF time how long you have *before* you get in the shower. From experience, after a week or two of the same routine, you’ll know exactly how much time you need/ have to shower (and do anything else).

Comment: @JoshK I didn't know that. However, it is also forbidden to daven when you have a smell of feces. (I recently visited a dairy farm in Israel. Farmer told me that they shower even on Yom Kippur after milking the cows, for this very reason I mentioned.)

Comment: @Loani Simple answer, of course. But, inevitably, it's not as much knowing how much time you need but while you're showering, you'll be cognizant of how much time you've spent and prob. thinking about finishing so that you can make the minyan.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55779/440

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. Also overlaps with https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78257/ and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73309/.

Comment: @DonielF. How is it any different than https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/what-can-one-learn-on-tisha-bav

Comment: ...or this https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75219/what-is-one-allowed-to-learn-on-tisha-bav