Torah thoughts conceived during davening
Are there any statements in Chazal (any era) about Torah ideas that one had during prayer accidentally (b'shogeg/b'ones) ch'v, when one should have been concentrating only on the words of prayer (Shulchan Aruch OC 101:1)?
Are they in any way suspect, or tainted (or anything else), by force of their conception in that inappropriate context?
[For example, we have statements that if one accidentally said the wrong beracha during Shabbat davening (i.e. said a weekday beracha - see ibid 268), it is a bad siman (see Shalah et al, based on Berachot 34b, Mishna 5:5). So, it is not inconceivable that there might be something similar, or derivative, regarding chiddushei haTorah (Torah novella) during tefilla.
Also related is the concept of chiddushei haTorah that one had in the bathroom, dealt with here (thanks Lanied Sofey)]

Bonus question:

If we do find a criticism of such divrei Torah/chiddushim, do we say that it is (in any way) worse to stray after thoughts of Torah, vs. mundane thoughts, during prayer?

(Let me know/vote if you think this should be separated out)

related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99178/what-are-the-practical-parameters-of-mitzvah-habaah-baveirah

Isn't there a story about the Vilna Gaon and a question he had in Kabbalah, and the answers he thought of when he was davening?

Bonus q 1  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55777/what-to-do-with-torah-novella-thought-in-the-bathroom-by-accident

@MichoelR Vilna Gaon was davening and got 7 different answers all at one time to a question he had in kabala, he spent a minute arranging his thoughts and went back to his shemona Esrei, when he finished he forgot the answers. There was Mussaf and when he davened again, the thoughts came to him again but this time he pushed them away and then he remembered them after. (back of Nefesh Hachaim)

Brachos 21a asks "these Bnei bei Rav" that make a mistake and say chol instead of Shabbos, what should they do. The Maadanei Yom Tov there, Ois Yud (in seemingly an explanation of why the bnei bei Rav were mentioned) says because they're so involved in their learning they make this mistake.

@LaniedSofey Perfect. Thanks for the reference!

I've heard that Reb Tzadok Hakohen miLublin refused to write down Torah thoughts he had during davening, as he perceived them as coming from the Sitra Achra. I don't have a source for that though.

@Yehuda interesing hurdle (I wouldn't call it impossible, especially for Reb Tzadok HaKohen) is that thinking "I will not write down this idea" is also a Torah thought, so need to make sure that one also defers that thought to after davening, otherwise it can lead to a double negative/paradox situation!
